# Pass Variable From JavaScript Function on Open.WIndow

Tags: php

I have to pass a string variable created in php to Javascript function to open form child using open.window. I have code like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
    function openWindow(v){
        WREF = window.open("test2.html?cad=e&cid="+v,"koreksi","width=550,height=350,top=50");
        if(!WREF.opener){ WREF.opener = this.window; }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php $var='Red'; ?>
<a HREF="javascript:void(0);" onClick="openWindow(<?php $var='Red'; ?>);">Open the window</a>
</body>
</html>
```

By those code, i hope i can get an address like this ***http://localhost/adduser.php?cad=e&cid=red***

Can you help me ? ( sorry i can't describe clearly for my q )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose the php variable in single quotes and echo it:
`<a HREF="javascript:void(0);" onClick="openWindow('<?php echo $var ?>');">Open the window</a>`

Edit: the single quotes are needed as the PHP echo will render the actual string, which will result in a javascript function call like: `openWindow(http://localhost/adduser.php?cad=e&cid=red)`, which is not valid syntax; on the other hand `openWindow('http://localhost/adduser.php?cad=e&cid=red')` is.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, and i tried to changed my code like this :

<body>
   <?php $var='Red'; ?>
   <a HREF="javascript:void(0);" onClick="openWindow('<?php echo $var; ?>');">Open the window</a>
</body>

unfortunately, the results of the link is not as I expected. This is the result link : 
http://localhost/adduser.php?cad=e&cid=<?php echo $var; ?>

What is wrong on my code above ?

Comment: Thank you for response. I think there is not any interpreter. The first php file is the above script ( my question above ). And the second file is like this : <?php
$cadd = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cad']);
$cuid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cid']);
echo $cadd;
echo $cuid;
?>

Comment: i used xampp. i acces the page from http://localhost/test1.html. Test1.html is the name of my php file

Comment: Yes .... thank you, you are correct. I changed test1.html to test1.php. Thank your advice

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<?php echo $var;?>` to pass variable

this line should be:--

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="openWindow('<?php echo $var;?>');">Open the window</a>
```

Comment: This will result in a javascript error, as $var should be enclosed in quotes.